# Matrix algebra for the sum of products

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

I have $T$ vectors $A_t$ $t=1,...,T$ of dimension $m\times 1$ and a vector $C$ of dimension $m \times 1$. Consider the matrix $D$ of dimension $m\times m$ defined as
$$
D:=\sum_{t=1}^{T}(A_t-C)(A_t-C)'
$$
Are there some algebraic properties of matrices that allow to obtain $D$ as the sum of two functions $f(\{A_t\}_{t=1,..T})$ and $g(C,T)$, i.e.
$$
D=f(\{A_t\}_{t=1,..T})+g(C,T)
$$?

Comment: What do you really want?  I dont think you can find what you ask for.

Comment: Ok, if you think that, you can just answer that there is no way to get that expression and possibly give some explanation

Comment: Just expand the product within the sum defining $D$. You will see it contains terms< of the form $A_t C'$ and C A_t'$ and those cannot be written in the form you ask for, except very special cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\widetilde A=\sum_{t=1}^T a_te_t^\top$ and $\widetilde C=C1^\top$, then
$$D=(\widetilde A-\widetilde C)(\widetilde A-\widetilde C)^\top$$

Comment: I have clarified my question. That expression is not what I'm looking for